# How can I get Sinatra to return a record matching today's date?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

My Sinatra app is a collection of notes. Each note is assigned a (future) date when it should be published:

```
class Note
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :publish_date, Date
  property :content, String                 
end
```

I'd like to create a route that will display only today's note, based on the publish_date:

```
get '/' do
  ...
  erb :today 
end
```

The note I want might be found using note.publish_date.to_s = Date.today.to_s but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to make this work. Thanks in advance for setting be straight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
get '/' do
    Note.first(:publish_date => Date.today) 
    erb :today 
end
```

perhaps?

Comment: @subpixel yeah, that's better :)